# Как изменить ссылку на phpbb?

Tags: phpbb, php

Добрый день, уважаемые коллеги, может быть кто-нибудь много работал с форумами на phpbb и знает, где можно изменить следующую вещь http://example.com/forum/ . Там есть кнопочка главная. Так вот при клике на нее нас переводит на некий сторонний сайт. Как можно исправить эту ссылку?

Что бы избежать лишних вопросов, сразу объясню: видимо, ссылка в слове "главная" запоминается форумом при установке. Но тут было такое дело, что сайт раньше располагался как раз таки по адресу http://example.com/ , но потом адрес был изменен, а вот как быть с форумом, не знаю.

Единственная мысль пришла в голову - снести к черту и поставить заново.

Подскажите, кто знает, как можно решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: в обеих пунктах]

Comment: Я просто phpBB плохо знаю, отвечал по аналогии с WordPress

Comment: Photon, посмотрим, если поможет - то айс.

Comment: В общем ни сработало. Снес форум. Сохранил шаблон. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: странно...

Comment: если изменение ссылки в настройках не влияет, значит оно hardcoded в шаблоне.

Comment: должно все было сработать. удалите куки на домена, и проверьте еще раз. хотя я так понял уже поздно :)

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по коду, поиск по базе..  Если где найдётся, заменить на текущий адрес..

Скорее всего в базе будет, хотя не факт.